# How can I resize an image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, resize

I'm new to web development.
I have a webpage in PHP in which there is an image.
I want to post this photo on a blog with this script

```
<div id="x"></div>

<script>
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://www.meteoarachova.com/stickersPWS/sticker.php";
var src = document.getElementById("x");
src.appendChild(img);
</script>
```

how can I resize the image and put a link for the blog visitor to return to the image page?

Answer (score 0):

Resize the image using `el.style.width = 50%;` and `img.style.height = 50%;` this will resize the images width and height by 50%. You can also use pixels or other size increments in CSS using `el.style.width/height`.

As for creating a link, if you want to use the image as a link, you could create an `a` tag and wrap it around the image controlling the size of image in that element. Then add the `href` attribute pointing to the page you wish to open when the user clicks the image.

```js
let div = document.getElementById("x");

let aTag = document.createElement("a");
aTag.href = 'http://www.meteoarachova.com/stickersPWS/sticker.php';
aTag.title = 'click to open image';
aTag.target = '_blank';
aTag.outline = 'none';

let img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://www.meteoarachova.com/stickersPWS/sticker.php";
img.style.width = '40%';
img.style.height = '40%';

aTag.append(img)
div.append(aTag);

console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0])
```

```html
<div id="x"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help
The original sticker is too large
http://www.meteoarachova.com/stickersPWS/sticker.php

 but the code limits the size to a specific size without being able to reach its full size